# Index was outside the bounds of the array in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting the below error with one of my Web API service:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Index was outside the bounds of the array.",
"ExceptionType": "System.IndexOutOfRangeException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
```

---

This error doesn't come while testing from RestClient for some time but if we start load testing on it, this error arises.

I am unable to resolve the issue so for fixing, I have done some changes in the connection string as below:

```
connectionString="Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=False;
Initial Catalog=xyz;Data Source=SQLSERVER1;User Id=sa;Password=****;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Asynchronous Processing=true; Connection Timeout=2147483647;
Pooling=true; Max Pool Size=200; Connection Lifetime = 0; ConnectRetryCount=2;
ConnectRetryInterval=2;"
```

Have I missed something somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going on a wild hunch here (since there is less then minimal information in your question) and i'll say you're updating a `List<T>` concurrently, from multiple threads. `List<T>` **is not thread-safe.**

If you're doing such work, use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead, or lock on the insertion to the list.

Comment: your direction helped me to solve a similar issue.Thanks.